# How to join two joined tables and group two different values

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble with getting the correct amount for PostsMade. What I want from the code is to view how many posts a user has read and also give a count of how many posts the user has created (including all users who have not made a contribution to the data as well). The count for the PostViewed is correct, however I'm stuck on getting the correct count for PostsMade. Here is the code I have atm:

```
Select User.Name, Count(VP.UserID) as PostsViewed, Count(MP.UserID) as PostsMade from 
(User as U1 left join MakePost as MP on (U1.UserID = MP.UserID)) inner join
(User as U2 left join ViewPost as VP on (U2.UserID = VP.UserID)) 
on (U1.UserID = U2.UserID)
group by U1.UserID, U2.UserID
order by PostsViewed DESC;
```

So the issue is that I also want to group PostsMade correctly as well, however it displays a false number. Any tips?

[MakePost-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2L6O.png)

[ViewPost-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SN2Q.png)

[User-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZkLi.png)

Comment: can you please show the structure of tables that you want to join

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Yes, of course. I have added those in the main post now.

MakePost:

| UserID | PostID | Time |


ViewPost:

| UserID | PostID | Time |

User:

| UserID | Email | Password | Name | Type |